# Drupal 9. Poniendo color picker para el color del precio del producto

Tags: twig, drupal, drupal9

estoy probando a hacer paragraph y tal. Y queria hacer una practica que seria tener en un **paragraph** un color picker del plugin : [Color Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/color_field) . Lo tengo bien instalado porque en otro componente si va todo bien, configuro el campo de mi paragraph : **field_color_precio_componente**.

Ya se ve como color picker a la hora de crear/editar ese **paragragrah**.
Y ahora estoy intentando que el precio de mi componente tenga asignado el color de ese color picker, el codigo que estoy implementando es el siguiente:

```
        <span
        {% if content.field_color_precio_componente|render is not empty %}
          style="
          font-size:100px;
          font-family:fantasy;
          {{content.field_color_precio_componente.0}};
          "
        {% endif %}
        >{{content.field_precio_component.0}}</span>
        <span style="font-size:30px;">
            {{content.field_tipo_moneda.0}}
            color:{{content.field_color_precio_componente.0}}
        </span>
```

Lo he querido imprimir como texto el valor que me devuelve para debugearlo un poco, y para mi sorpresa me de devuelve un codigo **hexadecimal + 1 numero**: `#c92222 1`. Por eso creo que no esta funcionando. Ahora mi pregunta es **¿Por que sale ese '1' ahi separado?**

He mirado el **format storage** del campo : **field_color_precio_componente** y esta seleccionado el del tipo : `#123ABC` asi que no entiendo muy bien ese 1 de donde sale.

**¿Alguna sugerencia?**

Answer (score 1):

Ya he encontrado la solucion, por lo visto ese **segundo numero es la cantidad de opacidad**, como no me interesaba ese argumento, me he ido a las propiedades de ese campo y le he dicho que no guarde la opcacidad, asi solo aparece el numero hexadecimal.